# iOS 8: New RWD/stylesheets piles buttons on left edge

Tags: bug, mobile-web, top-bar

The new Web UX has major topbar issues on Safari/iPad iOS 8.

- Everything on the top bar is in the wrong place. "StackExchange" has gone on holiday.
- Clicking "questions" (to the left of "tags")  on the top band actually takes you to your rep page.
- Clicking the "email" button opens the email, positioned about 300px left of the left edge, so you can only see the right edge of emails.
- Things outside the top bar/band seem to work.
- Same on all SE sites.  Quit app, reboot iPad, etc. all tried.

[image]

Comment: Considering they're currently on iOS 11... it's likely that the older versions are simply unsupported.

Comment: @Catija thanks for the info about what the current version is... not all hardware can run it... Is it SE policy to only support the latest & greatest platforms? Only certain platforms?

Comment: They have supported browsers listed here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/284336 iOS 9 is the oldest they support and that's from September 2015. I hardly call that the "latest and greatest".

Comment: Does the mobile version work ok?

Comment: Naw, you can select from the bottom. Safari on IOS is a bit notoriously buggy on SE - its a mobile view of the webpage and works better in some situations. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9W9o.png last option there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I didn't even know that was there! LOL!  I would probably not use it anyway, iPad is not a phone, it's a perfectly powerful desktop replacement. Being iOS is a curse, or rather, some people's viewpoints toward iOS is a curse, since around SE people seem to treat iOS like a phone OS arguing "well a 3 year old phone is obsolete".  A 3 year old iPad is not obsolete, and at $1000 for a good one, it ought not to be.

Comment: Oh, apparently newer versions of safari do that too. And the fact that you can't install a different rendering engine for no reason other than "apple says no" makes it hard to workaround.

Comment: Oh dear.  Even a vintage desktop Safari doesn't do it.  My lay impression was that Safari was WebKit, same engine as pretty much every other smart device browser...